# data.table: Proper way to do create a conditional variable when column names are not known?

Tags: r, data.table, if-statement

My question relates to the creation of a variable which depends upon other columns within a data.table when none of the variable names are known in advance.

Below is a toy example where I have 5 rows and the new variable should be 1 when the condition is equal to A and 4 elsewise.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Con = c("A","A","B","A","B"),
                 Eval_A = rep(1,5),
                 Eval_B = rep(4,5))
Col1 <- "Con"
Col2 <- "Eval_A"
Col3 <- "Eval_B"
Col4 <- "Ans"
```

The code below works but feels like I'm misusing the package!

```
DT[,Col4:=ifelse(DT[[Col1]]=="A",
                 DT[[Col2]],
                 DT[[Col3]]),with=FALSE]
```

**Update:**
Thanks, I did some quick timing of the answers below. Once on a data.table with 5 million rows and only the relevant columns and again after adding 10 non relevant columns, below are the results:

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
|         Method          | Only relevant cols. | With extra cols. |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| List method             | 1.8                 | 1.91             |
| Grothendieck - get/if   | 26.79               | 30.04            |
| Grothendieck - get/join | 0.48                | 1.56             |
| Grothendieck - .SDCols  | 0.38                | 0.79             |
| agstudy - Substitute    | 2.03                | 1.9              |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Look's like .SDCols is best for speed and using substitute for easy to read code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1. get/if** 
Try using `get` :

```
DT[, (Col4) := if (get(Col1) == "A") get(Col2) else get(Col3), by = 1:nrow(DT)]
```

**2. get/join** 
or try this approach:

```
setkeyv(DT, Col1)
DT[, (Col4):=get(Col3)]["A", (Col4):=get(Col2)]
```

**3. .SDCols** 
or this:

```
setkeyv(DT, Col1)
DT[, (Col4):=.SD, .SDcols = Col3]["A", (Col4):=.SD, .SDcols = Col2]
```

UPDATE: Added some additional approaches.

Comment: In the first answer, it should be `Col4 :=` or `c("Col4") :=`.

Comment: `data.table` generally isn't set up to take a character variable that refers to a column - but I think `get` is the best approach that works.

Comment: @Arun,  `Col4:=` and `c("Col4"):=` both literally give `Col4` as the column name but the desired column name is `Ans`, not `Col4`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, for some reason, when I first ran it, it gave me an error. I am unable to reproduce it now. I get your point.

Comment: I'm trying to work on the SDCols solution unsuccessfully. What is the explanation of `DT[, (Col4):=.SD, .SDcols = Col3]["A", (Col4):=.SD, .SDcols = Col2]`? 
`, (Col4):=.SD, .SDcols = Col3]` is "assign value of column 3 to the corresponding cell in Col4"? Is this the default option and then the second bracket is the actual condition `["A", (Col4):=.SD, .SDcols = Col2]`?
This second condition would be, if the key is "A", col4 equals Col2?

Answer (score 6):

Using `ifelse` and `get`:

```
DT[, (Col4) := ifelse (get(Col1) == "A",get(Col2) , get(Col3))]
```

Or using `substitute` to create the expression like this :

```
expr <- substitute(a4 := ifelse (a1 == "A",a2 , a3),
                   list(a1=as.name(Col1),
                        a2=as.name(Col2),
                        a3=as.name(Col3),
                        a4=as.name(Col4)))

DT[, eval(expr)]
```