# R Data.Table create a variable with a condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data.table

I need to create a new variable in the dataset below:

```
A  X
a  1
b  2
c  3
d  4
e  5
f  6
g  7
h  8
i  9
j 10
```

The `newvar` will have value 1 if `X` equals 2,5,7 or 9. Otherwise, `newvar` should be 0.

Code:

```
dt1 <- data.table(A = letters[1:10], X = 1:10, key = "X")
numberlist <- list(2,5,7,9)
```

I have tried the following based on a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450696/data-table-proper-way-to-do-create-a-conditional-variable-when-column-names-are):

```
dt1[, newvar:=.SD, .SDcols = 0][%in% numberlist, newvar:=.SD, .SDcols = 1]
dt1[, newvar:=.SD, .SDcols = 0][X %in% numberlist, newvar:=.SD, .SDcols = 1]
```

`dt1[, newvar:=.SD, .SDcols = 0]` means "assign value of 0 to newvar as default option. The second bracket `[%in% numberlist, newvar:=.SD, .SDcols = 1]` means "if the key (X) is included in the numberlist, set the `newvar` value to 1.

Any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
dt1[, newvar:=(X %in% c(2,5,7,9))+0L][]
#     A  X newvar
# 1: a  1      0
# 2: b  2      1
# 3: c  3      0
# 4: d  4      0
# 5: e  5      1
# 6: f  6      0
# 7: g  7      1
# 8: h  8      0
# 9: i  9      1
#10: j 10      0
```

Or if we already have the matching elements stored in a a vector

```
numberlist <- c(2,5,7,9)
dt1[, newvar:=as.numeric(X %in% numberlist)]
```

`as.numeric` is another option to coerce the logical vector to `0/1` values.

Comment: Thanks @akrun. It works but I still do not understand what's the logic behind. Why using two sets of `[]`. What was wrong in my code for not working?

Comment: @user3507584 The last set `[]` is just to print the output on the console.  The logic is using `%in%` to create the logical condition that will be TRUE when we match 2, 5, 7,9 with X and `+0L` coerces the logical vector to numeric 0, 1, you can also use `as.numeric` instead of `+0L`

Comment: maybe better (for reading and beginner) to use `transform(dt1, newvar=(dt1$X %in% c(2,5,7,9))+0L)` ?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel That would be for a data.frame  code. But, you don't need `dt1$X`, just ``X %in% ` would be sufficient. The OP created a data.table.

Comment: @user3507584 Just saw your `numberlist`.  It is better to create a vector i.e.  `numberlist <- c(2,5,7,9)`

Comment: @user3507584 Other thing I noticed in your code is using `.SDcols=0` and then assigning `newvar` to `.SD`.  I am not sure what you were trying there.  Also, it gave error message `dt1[,.SD,.SDcols = 0]#
Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, , .SD, .SDcols = 0) : 
  .SDcols is numeric but out of bounds (or NA)`

Comment: @akrun I was trying to replicate the example that I reference in the post. I opted for that because in the same post they compared the performance of three different alternatives and this was the fastest one (and I have 50M observations)

Comment: @user3507584 `.SDcols` is for selecting the columns.  For example if we need to multiple the 2nd column by 2, and create that as a newvar `dt1[, newvar:=.SD*2, .SDcols=2]`

Comment: @user3507584 If you have 50M obs, but a smaller number of unique values in `x`, you could try akrun's code with a `by=x` for speed (so it will test the `%in%` once per value of `x` instead of for each row).